# Array data appears as undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filter, undefined

I have an array declared as so:

```
$scope.test=['blah', 'blah2'];
```

And I wanted to use ng-grid as a test to merely display the data. I did the following:

```
$scope.sourceGridOptionsApprovers = {
    plugins: [gridLayoutPlugin],
    data : 'test',
    columnDefs: [
        {field: 'test', displayName: 'Approvers', width:'35%',
            cellFilter: 'stringArrayFilter'}
    ]
};
```

I wanted to filter the array so I could display the contents of test into one of my columns in ng-grid. I appended the following to my angular controller:

```
.filter('stringArrayFilter', function(){
        return function(myArray) {
            //console.log(myArray);
            return myArray.join(', ');
        };
    });
```

But when I try to display the contents of the array after I filter it, everything shows up as undefined, and I'm thinking it may be the way I passed in the array into the filter, but I'm not entirely sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a plunkr of my example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ba7hoGFhI7cWWaD3itZx?p=preview

Comment: Can you provide a plnkr?

Comment: Yes, here it is: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ba7hoGFhI7cWWaD3itZx?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i think ngGrid strictly requires a json object with properties to work on. Without properties the cell cannot be matched to specific data so the data for the cell is 'undefined' => which results in 'undefined' error messages.

So your data need to be like:

```
$scope.test=[{name: 'blah'}, {name: 'blah2'}];
```

Secondly the cellfilter is applied per row/cell and not over your whole array. With your example data the single cell data contains no arrays so you will get 'no method join' error messages.

The data should be structured like that with the use of your filter:

```
$scope.test = [{name: ['blah', 'blah2']}, {name: ['blah3', 'blah4']}];
```

Here is a full working example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/6EsriMwBNILKzwk3JIR1?p=preview

Comment: Interesting, I'm a bit confused because I asked a similar question, but the individual got the data to be parsed correctly as an array. Here is his plunkr.http://plnkr.co/edit/RKtxxKLB20fUuycfUlEH?p=preview I don't see the difference between his or mine however.

Comment: He is using the correct data structure that i explain above. `$scope.arrayOfStrings = ["test", "blah", "foo"];` is confusing you because it is used as displayed name for the column, but the real data array is not used in his example.

Comment: Oh, interesting. Thanks for informing me of this. I will probably have to change how the data is stored. I have one last question then: I am trying to access a certain field that is similar to what you provided in scope.test. It looks like so: `"canSendTo" : [{"id" : "public", "name" : "Public"}]`. Because the array is nested in an object already called source, I can't seem to access the name field in canSendTo. I tried doing: `field: 'canSendTo.name'`, with my data being the object `source`, but that returns nothing for me. Might you know how to work around this? If so that would be great!

Comment: You cannot bind a cell directly to the name property of canSendTo because it is an array. You need to handle the display of the nested array with objects yourself. Therefore the cellTemplate can be used. Here is an example http://plnkr.co/edit/cWbEvFoss7s9yepeRlXe?p=preview

Comment: Or you can bind the cell of ngGrid to the nth element of this array like so `{field: 'canSendTo[0].name', displayName: 'Approvers' }` but i think that isn't that what you want.

Comment: Your previous comment answered my question. Thank you for your help!